What's the main effect for a factor?
this is my first question on here. To add a little context: I'm studying the design of experiments and I'm having trouble with the part on the main effects of the factors. I understood that if you have $k$ factors with $2$ levels each, e.g. 0 and 1, with $n$ repetition, than the main effect, let's say, of factor $A$ is
$$
\delta A = \frac{[A1]-[A0]}{2 n}
$$
where $[A1]$ is the sum of the results when $A=1$ etc.
First question, why is that ? I mean why it is like this and not the contrary? i.e.
$$
\delta A = \frac{[A0]-[A1]}{ 2n}
$$
Second question, what is the main effect of a factor when it has more than two levels?
Third question, on my notes I have that the main effect of a factor "i" at the level "q" is
$$
\delta_{iq}=m_{iq}-m
$$
where $m$ is the mean of all the experiments apaprently and $m_{iq}$ is the mean of the experiments where the factor $i$ is equal to level $q$. Then if this is true than I don't understand why the first one is true.

Welcome to Cross Validated!  We are running into terminology problems here.  Normally "main effects" are contrasted with interaction effects rather than being used the way you are using the term.  Also, "factor analysis" refers to an entirely different procedure than what you are describing.  I've taken the liberty of changing your tags so as to make your question hopefully more amenable to helpful answers.

We can introduce some additional notation to see that the effect of factor $A$ is half the change in the expected response between the "control" group who have a factor to factor encoded as 0 and the "treatment" group who have the factor encoded as 1:
$$ \delta A = \frac{A1 - A0}{2n} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{A1}{n} - \frac{A0}{n}\right) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\bar Y_1 - \bar Y_0 \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left([\bar Y_1 - \bar Y] - [\bar Y_0 - \bar Y] \right).$$
The ordering of the difference comes from the convention to encode treatment and control groups as 1 and 0 respectively. Ignoring the multiplier of $\frac{1}{2}$, this definition of an effect has the nice interpretation of being the change in the expected response due to being treated (orange arrow in left-hand sketch below). As you suggest,this difference could be calculated the other way around but this would not have such a nice interpretation.
Depending on the context the idea of a control group might not be meaningful. For example, we might prefer not to describe an effect as that being male rather than female (or vice versa). Instead, we can describe the effect of a "sex" factor on an outcome relative to the overall average outcome across both levels of that factor (green arrows in left-hand sketch). This is precisely what $\delta A$ does by dividing by 2; it is making the implicit assumption that equal numbers of treated/untreated or male/female people within the experiment so that the overall mean response is half way between that of the two groups: $\bar Y = (\bar Y_1 + \bar Y_0 )/2$.

Your second and third questions come from extending this idea to multiple factor levels.
Suppose we have a factor taking 3 possible values, $a, b$ or $c$ and that most people have a factor value of "a", as in the right-hand sketch. One way to define the effect of this factor by quantifying how the expected response at each level of the factor differs from mean response over all levels. This is indicated by the green arrows in the right plot and is analagous to the example of a "sex" factor above.
Alternatively (and the default in some software) we could define the effect of the factor relative to a baseline level. This is appropriate when one level of the factor corresponds to a control group - for example if "a" is a control group given a placebo while "b" and "c" are two possible treatments, then the effect of the "treatment" factor taking level "b" migh better be descibed as $\left(\bar Y_b - \bar Y_a \right)$.

thank you so much
